# How to programmatically access Gmail chats?

Tags: backup, gmail

I want to add 'backupp Gmail chats' feature to Gmail Keeper at http://GmailKeeper.com

but the chats are not available when accessing Gmail account through IMAP, any other ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Labels:
Tick the checkbox next to "Show in IMAP" at the 'Chats' label